# Recorded conversations

Tags: united-kingdom, recording

In England, If I covertly record someone who is engaged admitting to an affair with me, is it illegal to share that with their fiance without their consent? If so, can I make their fiance aware that I have this recording?

Answer (score 1):

> In England, If I covertly record someone who is engaged admitting to an affair with me, is it illegal to share that with their fiance without their consent?

Yes, it is unlawful to share the recording without the consent of the person(s) recorded, unless you can demonstrate it is in the public interest - which seems unlikely in this context.

> If so, can I make their fiance aware that I have this recording?

Depends on your purpose. If it is merely to inform them then I don't think it is unlawful - if it is for (say) blackmail or extortion then it is unlawful.

Comment: I am reasonably sure that this is true, but it would, improve the answer if you could cite authority or a source.